# Force UEFI installation error

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I've made a bootable Linux USB generally following guides which recommend copying the img using `dd`. I've also used `UNetbootin` which I suspect is partially at cause for these errors (current image was not made with UNetbootin but I've tried starting the system with one that was before this).

Firstly, when installing I am required to do disk partitioning manually (rather than just saying "clean install over disk" or whatever, i have to manually create a partition for /, EFI boot loader and swap, usually something that is abstracted). After setting this up so I no longer get any warnings (it warns if the latter two are not included) I can move forward in the installer, the next page is where you set your location, however at this time the error shows up.

"this machine's firmware has started the installer in UEFI mode but it looks like there maybe existing operating systems already installed using "BIOS compatibility mode". If you continue to install Debian in UEFI mode, it might be difficult to reboot the machine into any BIOS-mode operating systems later.

If you wish in to install in UEFI mode and don't care about keeping the ability to boot one of the existing systems, you have the options to force that here. If you wish to keep the option to boot an existing operating system, you should choose NOT to force UEFI installation here."

Problem is, the system is effictively bricked. I'd be happy to force UEFI installation but clicking continue does nothing, clicking go back also does nothing. I suspect this "BIOS compatibility mode" OS it's recognizing is the remnants of an image made by UNetbootin however this was a fresh USB drive without UNetbootin ever installed. Any idea how to get past this? Anyway to reimage my USB(s) that ensure it will install correctly? fyi, I do not care about booting other OS' these systems are intended to run only Ubuntu and be up at all times. Any help appreciated.

Output from `diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            250.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *30.8 GB    disk3
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         4.1 KB     disk3s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS                         2.4 MB     disk3s2
```

Comment: Is the drive partitioned MBR or GPT? can you post your partition map?

Comment: @ravery I'm not entirely sure how to check but I'm going to edit the question with some info from `diskutil` on my Mac. I have a feeling I'm gonna need `/dev/disk3` to have a partitioning scheme more like the internal drive with EFI and GUID, right?

Comment: ah, it is neither ....  apple partitioning. Start the LiveCD and use `gparted` to create a GPT partition table and try to install.

Comment: @ravery any way to do this without a CD? I don't have an optical drive on any of these computers. During the installation (before the error occurs) I'm presented with a gui that lets me create a new partition table, in fact I have to do something here in order to move forward in the installer, so generally I made most of the volume `/`, added 52 MB EFI volume, a small swap space, then selected the EFI volume as the boot loader location and pressed continue at which point i get this error. Any tools to get this fully formatted from Mac/Bash? I was expecting a bootable image, not an installer...

Comment: you can do it from there.  how do you format the EFI partition? FAT is required. Live Images are available, but if the installer lets you create the partition table, you should be good.

Comment: @ravery one of the options is just EFI which is what I set it as (if I don't have some volume for EFI I get a warning encouraging me to set it before proceeding). I tried adding some FAT32 volume at `/boot` but that failed.

Comment: EFI partition flag is different from partition formating. Yes it must be flagged ESP and must be formatted with a FAT file system, usually FAT32.